# How to test for a global Toast/Snackbar with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a [material-ui `Snackbar` component](https://mui.com/components/snackbars/) in my root `pages/_app` file in my project. If a suitable event happens on any component in my project, it dispatches an action to `redux` to update the "alert" state of my store, which triggers the `Snackbar` to appear.

What source of approach can I use to run tests on a component level to track that relevant (and important) toast/snackbar messages appear due to events? Is this possible within the confines of react-testing-library?

##### tests for a given component interacting with snackbar

```js
import { render } from "@testing-library/react"; 
import user from "@testing-library/user-event";

describe("if the url is invalid", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(<SelectMedia />);
    user.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: /search/i }));
  });

  test("the VideoPlayer does not activate", () => {
    expect(screen.getByTestId())
  });
  test.todo("a warning toast message appears");
  // ^ what can I do to make tests like these work?
});
```

##### root app

```
const myApp = () => {
...
return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StyledSnackBar />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      // ^ all components (like SelectMedia) exist within <Component ... />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

- toast/snackbar *does not* exist within the `<SelectMedia />` component
- toast/snackbar *exists* on a root page as a sibling and uses redux to trigger behavior

Comment: I added an adjacent render for the `snackbar` in my tests, it seems to be working. I'll post a response/answer after some more testing.

Comment: Did you find the way to test your snackBar?

Comment: yeah, i also rendered it alongside SelectMedia, pretty much just repeat that line